# Compilation error when a thread invokes a function template (for a default argument)

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

The following function template is from Stroustrup's book ("CPL", 4th Ed):

```
template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Arg3>
void write(Arg1 a1, Arg2 a2 = {}, Arg3 a3 = {});

template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Arg3>
void write(Arg1 a1, Arg2 a2, Arg3 a3)
{
   thread::id name = this_thread::get_id();

   coutm.lock();

   cout << "From thread " << name << " : "
        << a1 << ' ' << a2 << ' ' << a3
        << endl;

   coutm.unlock();
}
```

I am trying to do the following [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b09aa0d1439ac17):
1) Invoke this function passing just 2 arguments. The third argument should default.
2) The function template invocation is passed *directly* to a thread (rather than through a lambda).

```
int main()
{
   thread t (write<char, float>, 'a', 4.9);

   t.join();
}
```

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:22:42: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, char, double)'

    thread t (write<char, float>, 'a', 4.9);
                                          ^
In file included from main.cpp:7:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/thread:118:7: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)

       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/thread:118:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:22:42: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'

    thread t (write<char, float>, 'a', 4.9);
                                          ^
In file included from main.cpp:7:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/thread:113:5: note: candidate: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)

     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/thread:113:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/thread:106:5: note: candidate: std::thread::thread()

     thread() noexcept = default;
     ^~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/thread:106:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
```

Is it possible to invoke such a function template *directly* through a thread, for a default argument? If so how? Or else, must a lambda be passed to the thread constructor?

Comment: 11.3.6 seems to suggest that adding default arguments later applies only to non-template functions. Don't know if the reverse applies. Stroustrup's example doesn't have an initial declaration and puts the defaults in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

A template argument cannot be deduced from a default (function) argument.  You didn’t specify `Arg3` explicitly, so there’s no way to instantiate `write`.  Put differently, what *type* do you expect `a3` to be in the thread’s call to `write`?

Comment: good point, but Ripi2's fix - which uses a default type - should have worked. But it doesn't.

Comment: @SSteven: I think there may be implementation bugs here: I see nothing in [thread.thread.constr](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.constr) or [func.require] to suggest that argument counts and types (here, a `double` argument for a `float` parameter) must match _more_ than for a normal call.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Arg3>
void write(Arg1 a1, Arg2 a2 = {}, Arg3 a3 = {});
......
thread t (write<char, float>, 'a', 4.9);
```

> Invoke this function passing just 2 arguments. The third argument
>   should default.

The compiler would use a default argument if it knows its type, which is not your case.

---

**The first fix** is to give a default *type of argument* to `write` declaration:

```
template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2, typename Arg3 = int> //default Arg3 type
void write(Arg1 a1, Arg2 a2 = {}, Arg3 a3 = {});
```

This still gives errors, well, new errors. I'm testing with g++ 7.3, clang 6.0.0  and icc 18.0.0 from [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Interestingly g++ allows the default type `typename Arg3 = int`, or a different type from declaration, also in the definition (in the next try, see below), but not only in the definition. Clang and icc fail in any case except the logical "in the declaration" only.

Try with the fix, but without a thread:

```
int main()
{
   //thread t (write<char, float>, 'a', 4.9);
   write<char, float>('a', 4.9);

   //t.join();
}
```

Ah ha. Now it compiles with g++ 7.3, clang 6.0.0  and icc 18.0.0 and outputs `a 4.9 0`

---

So the problem is with [std::thread constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) Why?

icc compiler expects the same number of functions arguments as the number of these arguments after template deduction, despite if they have default values (i.e. `= {}`) or not:

```
error: static assertion failed with "Wrong number of arguments for function"
        static_assert(sizeof...(_BoundArgs) == sizeof...(_Args),
        ^

          detected during:
            instantiation of class "std::_Bind_check_arity<_Ret (*)(_Args...), _BoundArgs...> [with _Ret=void, _Args=<char, float, int>, _BoundArgs=<char, double>]"  
            instantiation of class "std::_Bind_simple_helper<_Func, _BoundArgs...> [with _Func=void (&)(char, float, int), _BoundArgs=<char, double>]"
            instantiation of "std::thread::thread(_Callable &&, _Args &&...) [with _Callable=void (&)(char, float, int), _Args=<char, double>]"
```

clang error:

```
 error: no matching member function for call to '_M_invoke'
        -> decltype(std::declval<_Invoker&>()._M_invoke(_Indices()))
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~

 note: in instantiation of template class 'std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(char, float, int), char, double> >' requested here
         __make_invoker(std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
```

gcc error:

```
In instantiation of 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(char, float, int), char, double> >':
required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(char, float, int); _Args = {char, double}]'
required from here
error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(char, float, int), char, double> >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(char, float, int), char, double> >::_Indices)'
  operator()()
  ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: If you are not passing the write function template to a thread, it isn't necessary to specify the template arguments explicitly. The types would be inferred : `write('a', 4.9);` would work.